# Else than backtracking, how do I find longest path in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, backtracking

I have a graph shaped as a triangle.

```
      8
     / \
    1   4
   / \ / \
  4   2   0
 / \ / \ / \
9   1   9   4
```

In the above graph the longest path is `{8, 4, 2, 9}`

My current algorithm calculates the max number of the adjacent nodes and add it to the list, then calculates the sum of that list. This works in the above graph but won't work in situations such as this scenario:

```
      8
     / \
    0   1
   / \ / \
  4   0   4
 / \ / \ / \
9   99  3   4
```

My algorithm will mistakenly go through `{8,1,4,4}` where the correct longest path is `{8,0,4,99}`

The only solution I can think of is **Backtracking**. Where I have to go through all the paths and calculate the max path, which will be insanely slow in a huge graph. This about a 100k nodes graph.

My question is can I do better than this?

Comment: Longest path in your last example should be `{8,0,4,99}`

Comment: @jdigital yes you're right - corrected :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start at the top.

For each node, pick the maximum of its parents (the nodes above connected to it) and add its own value.

Then, in the last row, pick the maximum.

This will just give you the value of the longest path, but you could easily get the actual path by simply starting at the value picked at the bottom and moving upwards, always picking the greater parent.

The running time would be linear in the number of nodes.

**Example:**

Original:

```
First example:              Second example:
      8                           8
     / \                         / \
    1   4                       0   1
   / \ / \                     / \ / \
  4   2   0                   4   0   4
 / \ / \ / \                 / \ / \ / \
9   1   9   4               9   99  3   4
```

Output:

```
First example:                Second example:
      8                             8
     / \                           / \
    9   12                        8   9
   / \ / \                       / \ / \
  13  14  12                    12  9   13
 / \ / \ / \                   / \ / \ / \
22  15  23  16               21  111  16  17
```

Then you'd pick `23` for the first and `111` for the second.

To get the path, we'd have `23-14-12-8`, which corresponds to `9-2-4-8`, for the first, and `111-12-8-8`, which corresponds to `99-4-0-8`, for the second.

---

I'm of course assuming we have a tree, as stated. For general graphs, this problem [is quite a lot more difficult - NP-hard, to be exact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem).

Comment: It might be worth noting that the *path* can be recovered from you solution by starting from the maximum leaf and moving upwards, always following the greater parent.

Comment: @Heuster I thought about that, but it wont work. imagine this: {99,99,3,0} and {1,0,2,99} obviously starting from 0 at the button would be the correct way

Comment: @AK_ Heuster means you start from the maximum after running the algorithm presented in my answer. See edit.

Comment: @Dukeling brilliant! What is the expected time complexity of this? O(n+m)? where `n`=size of graph and `m`=size of last row

Comment: @AK_ If `n` is the total number of nodes, this would be `O(n)` (`O(n+m)` actually simplifies to `O(n)` because big-O ignores asymptotically smaller terms and `m < n`).

Comment: @Dukeling Well because it is a triangle graph `n ~= m` :) but yes you're right that is counted as `O(2n) = O(n)` - Thanks again!

Comment: @AK_ n = 1+2+3+...+m = [m(m+1)/2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2B2%2B3%2B...%2Bm) = O(m²).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need backtracking here - you can use breadth-first search to propagate the `max` for the path that you have found so far to the corresponding node, level by level.

- Start at the root, and set its `max` to its own value.
- Go through nodes level-by-level
- For each node check the `max` stored in its parent. There may be one or two of these parents. Pick the `max` of two `max`-es, add the value of the node itself, and store it in the current node
- When the path through the graph is complete, the result would look like this:

Max graph:

```
       8
      / \
     8   9
    / \ / \
  12   9   13
  / \ / \ / \
21  111 16   17
```

To recover a path, find the max value in the bottom layer. This is the final node of your path. You can reconstruct the path from the max graph and the original by starting at the max (111), subtracting the value (99), looking for the result (111-99=12) in the max graph, and continuing to that node until you reach the top:

- 111 - 99 = 12 -- Take 99
- 12 - 4 = 8    -- Take 4
- 8 - 0 = 8     -- Take 0
- 8 is the root -- Take 8

This gives you the max path in reverse. Note that this may not be the unique path (think of a graph filled with equal values to see how there may be multiple max paths). In this case, however, any path that you would recover will satisfy the max path requirement.